# Bootstrap of canvas when mobile and Bootstrap dropdown when desktop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

After user logs in, I have a user icon in the navbar. Clicking on it gives a user menu.

In desktop, I want to act this icon as dropdown.

[image]

In mobile, I want to act it as off canvas as shown [here](http://jsbin.com/AviNUxA/2/edit)

I can achieve both things separately.

I did not like the off canvas look for menu in the desktop so would like to use a dropdown but ofcanvas menu looks good in mobile and would like to use it in mobile.

So, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

I solved this.

I wanted to achieve this only with the media queries css way.

To achieve this I ended up using a js file for media queries using sth like

```
if(window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 767px)'))
  // logics to remove dropdown class and add a offcanvas class
```

I didn't like the solution much cuz it is messy and I am using like media queries in CSS and media queries in JS also.

For now I am leaving this question open with a hope that better solutions may come up.